# AT90SCR100 IC Chip: How can I clear (erase) the Lock Bits if LB2 is programmed?

Tags: avr

I have a question about [Atmel] AT90SCR100 IC Chip.

How can I clear (erase) the Lock Bits if LB2 is programmed ?

Best Regards,
Seikou Ishimaru.

Answer (score 1):

[Page 378](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Atmel%20PDFs/AT90SCR100_DS.pdf) of the datasheet gives you your answer:

"The Lock bits can only be **erased to “1”** with the **Chip Erase** command."

So send a chip erase command and **everything** gets cleared. That includes everything in the Flash and EEPROM. This is a security feature to allow companies to protect their IP from people who intend to make clones amongst other things. Once the lock bits are programmed it becomes impossible(*) to read back any of the memory contents of the device.

---

(*) technically it may be possible, but only by removing the epoxy and exposing exactly the right part of the chip to certain conditions which would require specialist equipment and knowledge. I put it here only as otherwise someone will undoubtedly comment and say that it is not entirely impossible.

Comment: Hi, I have already read Page 378 of the datasheet.But the Lock Bits could not be erased to "1" with the Chip Erase command.! Page 375:In Serial Programming Mode, the Lock bits are not erased with the Chip Erase command if LB2 is programmed See “Lock Bit Protection Modes(1)” on page 376.

Comment: @user3656778 could you post a link to the datasheet you are looking at - as page 375 in the one I put a link to us a load of sample code not the serial programming mode section.

Comment: There are two different memory lock bit groups, the boot lock bits (BLBxx) and the lock bits (LBx). The BLBxx cannot be changed if the LB2 is programmed. So chip erase wont clear these. *BUT* chip erase will clear the LB2 bit itself, which in turn then allows you to program the BLBxx bits again.

Comment: Hi, Chip Erase command could not clear the LB2 !!! In this case, the Chip is damaged ?

Comment: Hi, I referred TPR0327E – VIC – 10Nov14 of datasheet.

Comment: @SeikouIshimaru based on the datasheet you specified, yes it seems that LB2 cannot be cleared in "Serial Programming Mode" with a chip erase. It may still be possible (assuming the omission from the note on 375 is not a mistake) that you should be able to clear the LB2 bit with a chip erase if using the JTAG programming method. Otherwise it may not be possible at all - essentially this may be a flag to make the chip emulate a one-time programmable behaviour.

Comment: Hi, I will try use JTAG programming method.

Comment: Hi, I found that when I will try to use JTAG programming method, FUSEs bits must be set JTAG bit. So I must find another AT90SCR100 IC Chips.

Comment: Hi, I have found that AT90SCR100H (QFN64)  &  AT90SCR200H (QFN64) have only JTAG interface.
So I cannot check JTAG interface mode !!!, because I have only AT90SCR132LSD IC Chips.